# jQuery ajax: get original response text

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to get the original text of a ajax request. E.g if I set `contentType: 'application/json'`, I want to get a string in the success method and not a JSON parsed result. (I can't send the Content-Type header in the response from the server, because the server is not under my control).

Reason: the JOSN get from the server is nicly fromatted, and I lose this formation after the conversation.

Comment: which server side technology u are using

Comment: If you want a string, why should you set the contentType to 'application/json' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never lose the JSON, it just gets converted into a usable javascript object.

You can convert it back to a string using JSON.stringify(), or you can use it as the object it is suposed to be, or you can use the dataType option on your ajax request to tell jquery you want the string, not the object

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  dataType : "text"
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to what cernunnos posted:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "/your.json",
        beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            window.console.log(data);
        }
    });
</script>
```